# Including Terraform Configuration from Another Gitlab Project

Tags: gitlab, terraform, continuous-integration, cicd, configuration-as-code

I have a couple apps that use the same GCP project. There are `dev`, `stage`, and `prod` projects, but they're basically the same, apart from project IDs and project numbers. I would like to have a repo in gitlab like `config` where I keep these IDs, in a `dev.tfvars`, `stage.tfvars`, `prod.tfvars`. Currently each app's repo has a directory of `config/{env}.tfvars`, which is really repetitive.

Googling for importing or including terraform resources is just getting me results about terraform state, so hasn't been fruitful.

I've considered:

1. Using a group-level Gitlab variable just as `key=val` env file and have my gitlab-ci yaml `source` the correct environment's file, then just include what I need using `-var="key=value"` in my `plan` and `apply` commands.
2. Creating a terraform module that either uses `TF_WORKSPACE` or an input prop to return the correct variables. I think this may be possible, but I'm new to TF, so I'm not sure how to return data back from a module, or if this type of "side-effects only" solution is an abusive workaround to something there's a better way to achieve.

Is there any way to include terraform variables from another Gitlab project?

Comment: The root cause of all of this is the lack of a data source providing the necessary information for the project and environment lifecycles. If you fix that problem, then most of this technical debt will disappear.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard. I think you mean create my own [data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources). Do you mean I could create on and maintain it in a separate Gitlab project?